# Javascript str.replace with wildcard/regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I replace the `foo` part of the following? Is there a way to use a wildcard?

```
var str = "font-family:foo";
var res = str.replace("font-family:/*/","font-family:Times New Roman");
```

So that any `font-family: whatever` is replaced with `font-family: Times New Roman`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so simple, you could do it like this:

#### Regex

```
(font-family:)\w+
```

#### Replacement string

```
$1replacement
```

#### Online demo

http://regex101.com/r/dQ3uK4

Comment: Great answers all, thank you! Choosing this one for the excellent sharing of the http://regex101.com/r/dQ3uK4 , looks like a fine resource...

Answer (score 5):

you can try this:

```
var res = str.replace(/font-family:[^;}]*/g, "font-family:Times New Roman;");
```

The regex pattern must be delimited with `/`. The g flag is used to replace all substring found.

`[^;}]*` means all that is not a `;` or a `}` zero or more times.